# How to edit and validate JSON data using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I am getting and displaying json data for the selected file from `dropdown` in `textarea` successfully. Now my requirement is that I wanted to edit the json data for the selected file in `textarea` either using `angularjs`(`ng-jsoneditor`) or any `other libraries/tools` to validate. I have tried the following, but I cannot make it to work or integrate with this or any other `libraries` as expected to edit the content as it is giving: `object {0}  (empty object)` on default or clicking on `change options` button.

I am following [this](http://jsfiddle.net/angulartools/sd3at5ek/).

I have created the above code in [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/roer8KfZKaIiK4sFLrm5?p=preview).

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to use your own textarea instead of using the one built into the editor? There are buttons on the JSFiddle you linked that let you edit data or options on the fly.

Comment: @VishalKotcherlakota, thanks for your reply, I mean i don't have any reason to use textarea particularly, I can use any, but the intention is I need to display my json content for the selected file and then it should be editable to add some extra json fields also(it can be validated like like json editor of jsfiddle). Please let me know !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the "obj" object to the scope directly

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

    $scope.JSONFiles = [];
    $scope.obj = {data: '', options: { mode: 'tree' }}; 

    $http.get("test1.json").success(function (response) {
      $scope.JSONFiles.push(response);
    });
    $http.get("test2.json").success(function (response) {
       $scope.JSONFiles.push(response);
    });

    $scope.selectedjson ="";
    $scope.textAreaData = "";
    $scope.optionChanged = function(){
      $scope.textAreaData = $scope.selectedjson;
     // alert($scope.textAreaData);//gives selected file json data
      // code to implement json-editor

       $scope.obj = {data: $scope.textAreaData, options: {mode: 'tree'}};
            $scope.onLoad = function (instance) {
                instance.expandAll();
            };
            $scope.changeOptions = function () {
                $scope.obj.options.mode = $scope.obj.options.mode == 'tree' ? 'code' : 'tree';
            };
    };

});
```

[Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/IZgnF99hoXlltsacDPGs?p=preview) a working Plnkr. 
The example in the docs also shows [this](https://github.com/angular-tools/ng-jsoneditor)

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Yes, I forgot it and it's working fine your Plnkr too ! Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: I have one small query that if we observe clearly, some slashes("/") are coming for the selected json data ? How to remove those in <div>'s content ? May I know why these are coming ?

Comment: The json is being stringified, meaning: The json contains " and to make them into one string the JSON.stringify() is being called which adds / infront o. If you want to remove them you can use JSON.parse()

Comment: yes, I got it and working fine ! Thanks for your valuable support !

Comment: No problems! Have a nice day